# ¿Cómo muestro un dato exacto de un usuario con PHP y MYSQLI?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

En realidad tengo poco conocimiento de PHP pero estoy intentando formular lo siguiente:

Tengo 400 cuentas registradas en mi base de datos. Cada cuenta tiene un **valor específico** que contiene un número o un texto. Quiero decir:

```
ID CUENTA CONTRASEÑA CANTIDADDINERO NOMBREDELAMASCOTA (por ejemplificar)
01 Stack   Over         4000           Bicho
02 Over    Stack        3200           Marrano
03 Todo    Bien         400            Grosero
```

En este caso, lo que quiero hacer es: a través de un login con PHP y MYSQLI, el que llevándome a una página 'inicio', me pueda arrojar (con una consulta, supongo) los datos del usuario que **ha** iniciado sesión.

```
Hola Stack

Tienes 4000 de dinero
Tu mascota se llama Bicho
```

Esto, creado de tal manera que cada usuario que haga login pueda obtener **su** cantidad de dinero y el nombre de su mascota.

Mi pregunta final es: ¿Qué tipo de Syntaxis debo de utilizar? ¿Podrían dejarme algún ejemplo por favor? Obviamente investigaré por mi cuenta, pero si me dan una mano me vendría genial.

Muchas gracias y que tengan buen día.

Comment: necesitamos saber como almacenas el nombre del usuario que inicia sesión, segundo si estas conectandote por mysqli o pdo, tercero lo que has tratado hasta el momento

Answer (score 0):

Lo primero que debes tener en cuenta es que al hacer login debes guardar los datos del usuario de forma temporal. Puedes usar `$_SESSION` o `$_COOKIE` para mantener esos datos al alcance.

Supongamos que necesitas guardar *ID, CUENTA, CANTIDADDINERO y NOMBREDELAMASCOTA*.

El código sería algo así:

```
$ID = (int) $_POST['_ID']; // Suponiendo que ya tienes el ID después de hacer login.

$mysqli = new mysqli('127.0.0.1', 'tu_usuario', 'tu_contraseña', 'tu_base_de_datos');

$sql = "SELECT ID, CUENTA, CANTIDADDINERO, NOMBREDELAMASCOTA FROM tu_tabla WHERE ID = " . $ID;

$result = $mysqli->query($sql);

$row = $result->fetch_assoc(); // Siendo '$row' la variable que tiene los datos del usuario autenticado/logueado obtenido a través del Query que se hace anteriormente vinculado a un ID.

$_SESSION['ID'] = $row['ID'];
$_SESSION['CUENTA'] = $row['CUENTA'];
$_SESSION['CANTIDADDINERO'] = $row['CANTIDADDINERO'];
$_SESSION['NOMBREDELAMASCOTA'] = $row['NOMBREDELAMASCOTA'];
```

Luego en tu archivo PHP donde quieres que se vea el mensaje, sería algo como:

**archivo.php**

```
<?php
echo "Hola " . $_SESSION['CUENTA'] . "<br /><br />";
echo "Tienes $ " . number_format($row['CANTIDADDINERO'], 2) . "de dinero.<br />";
echo "Tu mascota se llama " . $_SESSION['NOMBREDELAMASCOTA'];
?>
```

Espero te sirva de ayuda.

Comment: y aqui donde se muestra como obtenerlo desde la base de datos?

Comment: Ya quedó el código para hacer el query junto con la línea para hacer la conexión por si desconoces como hacerlo.